# Reactjs Render issue on popover with data fetched from BE

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

Here is the sandbox for the issue https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-cache-kl12v

I am using antd for designing the website. Currenly I need to show notifications to user and there is notifications icon on the top right hand side of the navbar.

I rendered it using Popover from antd design and when clicked on it, it will fetch the data from BE and display them.

The issue is the popover dialog box is rendering outside of the viewport and making horizontal scrollbar to appear. I want to show the popover with content without the dialog stretching out of the view port and without horizontal scrollbar.

I have tried with overflow-x: hidden attribute to hide the scrollbar, the scrollbar is hidden but the popover content is not visible. Please help !

Comment: um your InfiniteScrollExample.js file is empty

Comment: Hi Akshay kishore, can you check once as all the codes are still available

Answer (score 0):

The popover is positioned "absolute" with left as **calc(100% - 40%) !important**.

You can do one thing. Give the "ant-popover" class a CSS of **right:0**. It will then remove the horizontal scroll.

Comment: sorry I was trying for some fix with calc(100% - 40%) !important. but that didn't work as expected, with CSS right:0 also is not working, can you pls help

Answer (score 0):

Let's define a callback function in the parent of `InfiniteScrollExample` as:

```
onInfiniteScrollUpdated = () => {
  this.setState({InfiniteScrollUpdate: this.state.InfiniteScrollUpdate + 1})
}
```

And let's pass this method as a prop to `InfiniteScrollUpdate` as:

```
<Popover
  placement="bottomLeft"
  title={text}
  content={<InfiniteScrollExample />}
  trigger="click"
  afterInfiniteScrollApiSuccess={this.onInfiniteScrollUpdated}
>
   <Button>Msgs</Button>
</Popover>
```

And in `InfiniteScrollExample` you'll have to call this prop after the BE call is successful and the view is updated. If you make the BE call in componentDidMount, it would look something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(url).then(res => {
    this.setState({apiRes: res.data}, this.afterInfiniteScrollApiSuccess);
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi, in this screenshot you have static content on the popover so it is rendered properly but when we fetch data from BE, the popover size varies and overflows out of the view port. can you pls try with dynamic content

Comment: Got it... Can you have a loading component for the time when response is not ready, and point `InfiniteScroll` component only when the response is received. Something like: `<Popover content={this.state.popoverApiResponse ? <InfiniteScrollExample /> : <Loading />} />`

Comment: Actually the InfiniteScrollComponent is full built one and will get response when u click on the popover and when u scroll, it will again call BE to get few more items. If you check my sandbox only the first click on the popover has the issue, because initially there is no data and popover window is small but when data is received the popover window expands beyond viewport and on the further click on it the window is automatically adjusted. If able to resolve the initial one it would be very helpful

Comment: What I am suspecting is, at the first click, `InfiniteScrollExample` is blank and hence must be occupying lesser space. And when BE call is successful, `InfiniteScrollExample` grows in size without letting the `Popover` know that it has been re-rendered. If you fix your code in a way to re-render the parent of `InfiniteScrollExample` when it grows in size, the problem might get fixed. Maybe you can send a callback function as a prop to `InfiniteScrollExample`.

Comment: awesome yes bro i am also thinking the same, but not sure how to do it

Comment: I've updated the answer with the solution which I think might solve your problem. Let me know in case this works/fails.